# Android force close on parsing integer and referencing button

Tags: android, parseint, forceclose

this first activity takes the name and the password of the user if he already has an acount the second view class will opened else the user should sing up first.

i have two common problems:
**1-** the parse of integer cause force close notified by logcat

**2-** the second button make also force close

---

```
package sarah.android;
import android.R.integer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SelesMeter2Activity extends Activity
implements OnClickListener{
EditText ed1;
EditText ed2;
Button b1;
Button b2;
SQLiteDatabase sql;
Cursor c;
Intent in;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ed1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed1);
    ed2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed2);
    b1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt1);
    b2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt2);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    sql=openOrCreateDatabase("db",0, null);
    sql.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists " +
            "Employee2 (password integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,name text           NOT NULL)");
 }
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //log in 
    if(arg0.getId()==R.id.bt1)
    {
        String name=ed1.getText().toString();
        Integer pass=Integer.parseInt
                (ed2.getText().toString());
        if(c.getCount()!=0)
        {
    c=sql.rawQuery("select * from Employee", null);
    while(c.moveToNext())
    {
    if(name.equals("c.getString(1)")&&pass==c.getInt(0))
    {
        in=new Intent(this,secondview.class);
        startActivity(in);
        break;
    }
    }
        }

    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"please sign up first or enter " +
                "correct data", 2000).show();
    }

    }
    else if(arg0.getId()==R.id.bt2)
    {
        //sign up
    Intent  in2=new Intent(this,signup.class);

        startActivity(in);

    }
}   
}
```

the sing up class that enter the new information of the user :
       package sarah.android;

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

   public class signup extends Activity
   implements OnClickListener{
EditText e1;
EditText e2;
SelesMeter2Activity obj;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.singupx);
    Intent in =getIntent();
    e1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed1s);
    e2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed2s);
    obj=new SelesMeter2Activity();
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String n=e1.getText().toString();
    int p=Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());
    obj.sql.execSQL("insert into Employee2        (password,name)values('"+n+"',"+p+")");

}

}
```

Comment: i want to convert the edittext value into integer without force close

Comment: i have number formate Exception on log cat

Comment: `Integer.parseInt` should work fine. What is the actual text in your `ed2s` `EditText`?

Comment: @SarahAabed : you will need to check EditText is empty or not before converting it to integer

Comment: @Eric it depends on user suppose any number it should be his password

Comment: @imrankhan how i can check that the edit empty or not ...i am sorry i still beginner in android !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check first if the text you are converting is a numerical value; otherwise, `parseInt(...)` will fail.

You can do this using `try/catch`:

```
String sp = e2.getText().toString();
try {
    // Attempt to parse the number as an integer
    int p=Integer.parseInt(sp);
    // This insertion will *only* execute if the parseInt was successful
    obj.sql.execSQL("insert into Employee2        (password,name)values('"+n+"',"+p+")");
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    // parseInt failed, so tell the user it's not a number
    Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry, " + sp + " is not a number. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Great thanks for your time Eric but i still have the same problem :

Comment: log cat error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer

Comment: i modified the on click code in the first activity to surround it by try catch as you said this is the modified section:
if(arg0.getId()==R.id.bt1)
  {
   int p=0;
   String name=ed1.getText().toString();
   String sp = ed2.getText().toString();
   try {
       // Attempt to parse the number as an integer
        p=Integer.parseInt(sp);
       }
   catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
       // parseInt failed, so tell the user it's not a number
       Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry, " + sp + " is not a number. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: Then the error is probably coming from `Integer pass=Integer.parseInt` in your other `onClick` method. You should modify that code in the same manner as this one.

Comment: Update your original post with the code you are using now, then.

Comment: Then please close this question (by accepting the answer) and start a new question with the full LogCat output as well as the code it pertains to.